# Range of $f(x)=\frac{(x+a)^2}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{(x+b)^2}{(b-a)(b-c)}+\frac{(x+c)^2}{(c-a)(c-b)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, contest-math

> Consider $$f(x)=\frac{(x+a)^2}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{(x+b)^2}{(b-a)(b-c)}+\frac{(x+c)^2}{(c-a)(c-b)}$$ (where $a,b,c$ are distinct real numbers). If $p$ denotes the number of natural numbers in the range of $f(x)$, then find $p$.

I have no idea of how to proceed this question. Hence not able to provide the requisite steps.

What can be seen is: $$f(0)=\frac{a^2}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{b^2}{(b-a)(b-c)}+\frac{c^2}{(c-a)(c-b)}\,.$$
That is,
$$f(0)=-\frac{a^2(b-c)+b^2(c-a)+c^2(a-b)}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}\,.$$
This implies
$$f(0)=-\frac{a^2(b-c)+bc(b-c)-(b^2-c^2)a}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}\,.$$
Thus
$$f(0)=-\frac{(b-c)\big(a^2+bc-(b+c)a\big)}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}\,.$$
Consequently,
$$f(0)=-\frac{(b-c)(a-c)(a-b)}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}=-(-1)=1\,.$$
So, at least we know $p\geq 1$.

Comment: The function can be written as a quadratic, so it's not bounded (either above or below), so $p=\infty$

Comment: But answer if f(x)=1, so p=1. I don't have the solution to it

Comment: Substitute $x=-a$ and see what happens. Similarly for $x=-b$ and $x=-c$.

Comment: I presume that if we open the bracket the coefficient of $x^2$ and $x$ will vanish and the constant term will be equal to 1 but any shortcut method

Comment: @timon92 awesome!

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi A parabola can have the same $y$ value at atmost two points, since in this case $f(-a)=f(-b)=f(-c)$, $f(x)$ must be a constant function.

Comment: I cross checked it after substitution the answer is f(x)=1

Comment: This seems to be a particular case of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2681436/proving-an-identity-for-complete-homogenous-symmetric-polynomials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of having this thread answered, I first restate [timon92's hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746911/range-of-fx-fracxa2a-ba-c-fracxb2b-ab-c-fracxc#comment7705170_3746911).  Observe that $f(x)=1$ for $x\in\{-a,-b,-c\}$. Since $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $2$, we conclude that $f(x)=1$ identically.  Therefore, $p=1$.

Alternatively, note that
$$f(x)=Ax^2+2Bx+C\,,$$
where
$$A:=\sum_{\text{cyc}}\,\frac{1}{(a-b)(a-c)}\,,$$
$$B:=\sum_{\text{cyc}}\,\frac{a}{(a-b)(a-c)}\,,$$
and
$$C:=\sum_{\text{cyc}}\,\frac{a^2}{(a-b)(a-c)}\,.$$
Define
$$\alpha(x):=\sum_{\text{cyc}}\,\frac{(x-b)(x-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)}\,,$$
$$\beta(x):=\sum_{\text{cyc}}\,a\,\frac{(x-b)(x-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)}\,,$$
and
$$\gamma(x):=\sum_{\text{cyc}}\,a^2\,\frac{(x-b)(x-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)}\,.$$
Then, $\alpha$ is the Lagrange polynomial iterating the points $\big(x,\alpha(x)\big)=(x,1)$ for $x\in\{a,b,c\}$.  Therefore, $\alpha(x)=1$ identically.  Similarly, $\beta(x)=x$ and $\gamma(x)=x^2$ identically.

Now, if $[x^k]q(x)$ denotes the coefficient of $x^k$ in a polynomial $q(x)$, then
$$A=[x^2]\alpha(x)=[x^2](1)=0\,,$$
$$B=[x^2]\beta(x)=[x^2](x)=0\,,$$
and
$$C=[x^2]\gamma(x)=[x^2](x^2)=1\,.$$
Thus, $f(x)=Ax^2+2Bx+C=0x^2+2\cdot 0x+1=1$, so $f(x)=1$ identically.